# How to set different modules for testing (other than for prod) in Koin Android?

Tags: android, koin

I want inject Koin in this project https://github.com/android/architecture-samples/tree/usecasesrename/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp.
They have a RealRepository for prod and FakeRepository for testing purposes. I can easily change modules in Application

```
class MainApplication : Application() {

override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()

    startKoin {
        // module list
        modules(Repository())
        //modules(FakeRepository())
    }
  }
}
```

but it is manual work and means that every time I want to run tests I have to substitute it here. Is there a way such depending on the use cases Koin would give me the right modules?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: unfortunatly no